# Autotypers (pyautogui, java.awt.robot) not working on an Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: java, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, pyautogui

I'm trying to recover my root password by automatically typing into a running Oracle VM VirtualBox. I've tried using Java.awt.robot and pyautogui to complete the task.

They both are successfully able to click on the VM, and they are both able to type into a word document on my actual computer, but no keystrokes are being interpreted by the VM (which is where my problem occurs).

I have Auto Capture Keyboard turned off now, but still doesn't work.

Python version:

```
import pyautogui

# location of where I am putting the console
pyautogui.moveTo(589, 973)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello, world')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Java version:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // location of where I am putting the console
        robot.mouseMove(589, 973);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

        // testing to see if the enter key will work
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
}
```

Both versions will click the VM, but neither will type anything in it nor press enter key
[image: Oracle VM Ubuntu recovery mode]

Is this a silly way of trying to type into the VM? Is there an easier method for sending input and keystrokes to a VM? What am I doing incorrectly for the input not to be typing into the VM?

(I am not looking to simply press Control-D to bypass the password.)

Short video of it working on a local document, but not on VM: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM9dVjzzEbI&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu as host, the Java version is working fine. It is able to transfer focus and type something in LibreOffice. I have also added `Thread.sleep(100);` before `keyPress` method.

I am using VirtualBox version 5.2 with extension pack installed. Both machines are running Ubuntu 16.04. The problem might be related to Windows host.

Comment: Congrats, nobody else answered the question. So, you get the points by default.